# Jquery selector with variable can not run click()

Tags: jquery

I have a form with id "submit_section2".

I try trigger click event of a button by jquery with a code `$("#submit_section2").click()` => it's work.

But when I try something like

```
var idButtonSave = "submit_section2";

$('#' + idButtonSave).click(); // function click not run
```

The trigger not hit to the button.

What wrong with my code?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please add your code and proper question which describe your problem statement

Comment: Could you please add your complete code ? ? ?

Comment: thank you! Actually, idButtonSave has wrong id of element

Answer (score 0):

Running all the following on my side works.

```
var idButtonSave = "submit_section2";

$('#' + idButtonSave).click(() => {
  console.log("Working");
})

$('#' + idButtonSave).click();

if ($('#' + idButtonSave).click();) {
  console.log("Working");
}
```

Perhaps you are trying to call idButtonSave but it was defined as a local.
If so try `idButtonSave = "submit_section2";`